# Assets doesn't refresh after deleting folder

Tags: assets

When a new subfolder is created and deleted right after, the refresh button keeps spinning and the folder still appears in the list. This only happens when no files are uploaded into it. After a page refresh the folder is deleted.

I have updated assets to v2.1.3

Any ideas why the refresh isn't triggering?

**support answer:**

ahh, the old trick with glob() returning false instead of an empty array on servers with open_basedir set to On.

Can you open up source.ee.php file in third_party/assets/sources/ee folder, locate the method _delete_source_folder and replace it with the one I'm attaching? That should fix your problem. Also, no matter how trustworthy I sound, always back up your files before doing stuff like this :)

Alternatively, you could wait a day and a half - word on the street is that Assets 2.1.4 might be released tomorrow US time, that would have this and a bunch of other bugfixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an unexpected Ajax response when deleting the empty folder. Since I can't reproduce this on my end, could you send over CP access to support@pixelandtonic.com so we can take a closer look?